# SQL algorithm with three identifiers from one table

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, codeigniter

Probably this will be really easy, but I can't figure out, how to get necessary values from my DB with one query. Just can't figure it out now. I'm going to make this query inside CodeIginiter system.

Table 'information' construction:

```
CREATE TABLE information (
    planid int(11) NOT NULL,
    production_nr int(11) NOT NULL,
    status int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

Table 'information' content:
[image]

Necessary output:
I would like to get (at the best - with only one query, but if its not possible, then with multiple) all planid's where: ALL of this plan id's pruduction_nrs has status >= 3.

In this case, I would need to get these plandid's: 2 and 5 because each of these planid's ALL production_nrs has status greater or equal than 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select planid, production_nr
from information inf1
where not exists (select 1 from information inf2
                  where inf1.planid = inf2.planid
                  and   status < 3)
```

You might consider amending the select clause (first row) according to your needs:

- Add distinct (if the table PK includes status column)
- Change the column list

Comment: The execution plan for the query would be probably: 1. the main query does sequential full table scan. 2. for each row the sub-query would check whether given planid has rows that doesn't fit the requirement status >= 3. On the first row found the sub-query stops.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT planid , production_nr FROM  information
WHERE production_nr IN(SELECT production_nr FROM information) AND STATUS >=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is known as relational division. There are basically two ways to approach it

1) planid where it does not exist a production_nr with status < 3

```
select planid 
from information i1
where not exists (
    select 1 from information i2
    where i1.planid = i2.planid
      and i2.planid < 3
)
```

2) planid where the number of production_nr is equal to the number of production_nr with status >= 3. I'll leave that as an exercise ;-)