# SQL Server matching all rows from Table1 with all rows from Table2

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

someone please help me with this query,
i have 2 tables

**Employee**

```
EmployeeID   LanguageID
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            1
2            3
3            1
3            2
4            1
4            2
4            3
```

**Task**

```
TaskID   LanguageID   LangaugeRequired
1        1            1
1        2            0
2        1            1
2        2            1
2        3            1
3        2            0
3        3            1
```

LangaugeID is connected to table langauge (this table is for explaination only)

```
   LangaugeID   LanguageName
   1            English
   2            French
   3            Italian
```

is there a possilbe way to make a query which gets employees where they can speak all the languages required for each task?

for example:

1. Task ID 1 requires only LanguageID = 1, so the result should be EmployeeID 1,2,3,4
2. Task ID 2 requires all 3 languages, so the result should be EmployeeID 1,4
3. Task ID 3 requires only LanguageID = 3, so the result should be EmployeeID 1,2,4

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: It's called relational division. See if my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929652/sql-algorithm-with-three-identifiers-from-one-table/23929856#23929856 helps.

Comment: @Lennart - Can you please tell me if my answer is okay ? Is it nice ? Thanks. Chenqui.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is another variant to do this:

```
select t1.taskid, t2.employeeid from
(
    select a.taskid, count(distinct a.languageid) as lang_cnt
    from
    task as a
    where a.LangaugeRequired=1
    group by a.taskid
) as t1
left outer join
(
    select a.taskid, b.employeeid, count(distinct b.languageid) as lang_cnt
    from
    task as a
    inner join
    employee as b
    on (a.LangaugeRequired=1 and a.languageid=b.languageid)
    group by a.taskid, b.employeeid
) as t2
on (t1.taskid=t2.taskid and t1.lang_cnt=t2.lang_cnt)
###
here you can insert where statement, like:
where t1.taskid=1 and t2.employeeid=1
if such query returns row - this employee can work with this task, if no rows - no
###
order by t1.taskid, t2.employeeid
```

as you see, this query creates two temporary tables and then joins them.

first table (t1) calculates how many languages are required for each task

second table (t2) finds all employees who has at least 1 language required for task, groups by task/employee to find how many languages can be taken by this employee

the main query performs LEFT JOIN, as there can be situations when no employees can perform task

here is the output:

```
task    employee
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       1
2       4
3       1
3       2
3       4
```

update: simpler, but less correct variant, because it will not return tasks without possible employees

```
select a.taskid, b.employeeid, count(distinct b.languageid) as lang_cnt
from
task as a
inner join
employee as b
on (a.LangaugeRequired=1 and a.languageid=b.languageid)
group by a.taskid, b.employeeid
having count(distinct b.languageid) = (select count(distinct c.languageid) from task as c where c.LangaugeRequired=1 and c.taskid=a.taskid)
```

Comment: Your 1st query is correct, can you please just make this query with conditions? for example, test if EmployeeID 1 is suitable for TaskID 1

Comment: the simpler query is giving me an error on sql server 2008 -> Invalid column name 'lang_cnt'

Comment: I'm fairly certain `languageId` will be distinct per-task, so you likely don't need `DISTINCT`.  You're also likely to get faster results by pushing the predicates into the relevant CTEs (why generate rows if you don't need them later?).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I agree about distinct, but I cannot be sure as we don't have actual table ddl. I wrote this query in mysql and was too lazy to find any online sql server to try with CTE :)

Comment: For the record my approach will NOT work - For each employee, find the number of languages (`X`) they can speak for each task. Then, find out the number of languages (`Y`) needed for a task. If `X = Y`, then the employee qualifies for the task. An example for where this will fail - when a task and an employee have two languages each, but the languages known by emp is not the same as required by task.

Answer (score 1):

Another version using `NOT EXISTS`

Retrieve all task-employee combinations where a missing language does not exist

```
SELECT t1.EmployeeId, t2.TaskId
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID
    FROM Employee
) t1 , (
    SELECT DISTINCT TaskID
    FROM Task
) t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (   
    SELECT 1 FROM Task t
    LEFT JOIN Employee e 
        ON e.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID
        AND e.LanguageID = t.LanguageID
    WHERE t.TaskID = t2.TaskID
    AND LanguageRequired = 1
    AND e.EmployeeID IS NULL
)
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3c78/1

Comment: Sorry Fuzzy Tree. my bad. Upvoted your neat query. Can you please give me some feedback for my query. Is it okay ? Is it nice ? Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

You could use a `Join` logic to get the result, something like:

```
SELECT a.EmployeeID FROM Employee a, Task b WHERE b.LanguageRequired == a.LanguageID;
```

Comment: there is no == in sql server, and this query shows all employees 5 times

Comment: Overly simplistic.  I'm not aware of _any_ RDBMS with a `==` (double-equals) operator - everything is context based.